# Citing page numbers in parentheses with year but author outside

Tags: citing, brackets

So I want the following:

The three parameter inverse gamma distribution is described by Malamud et al. (2004, p. 694) as...

The script I'm using is:

```
The three parameter inverse gamma distribution is described by \cite[p. 694]{Malamud2004c} as...
```

And I'm getting:

The three parameter inverse gamma distribution is described by (Malamud et al., 2004, p.694) as...

Any ideas??

Comment: looks like a job for `natbib` and `\citet`; i'm sure this has been asked before, but i can't find a good match.  `texdoc natbib` on a tex live installation to look at the documentation.

Comment: Since asking this I found this site...  http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php

Answer (score 5):

Since an MWE wasn't provided, I'm making a number of guesses about your reference/citation style. The desired format is known as an in-text citation, while the standard `\cite` command provides only parenthetical citations.

The [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package provides `\citep` for parenthetical citations and `\citet` for in-text citations.

Here's a basic example showing the usage of both citation types with `natbib`. I guessed at the particular article cited and the bibliography style in use, but this solution works in general:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe_refs.bib}
@article{Malamud2004c,
  title={Landslide inventories and their statistical properties},
  author={Bruce D. Malamud and Donald L. Turcotte and Fausto Guzzetti and Paola Reichenbach},
  journal={Earth Surface Processes and Landforms},
  volume={29},
  number={6},
  pages={687--711},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % adjust to suit your requirements

\begin{document}
The three parameter inverse gamma distribution is 
described by \citet[p. 694]{Malamud2004c} as\dots

Other researchers in the field described the three parameter 
inverse gamma distribution as\dots \citep[p. 694]{Malamud2004c}.

\bibliography{mwe_refs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`\citeA[p. 694]{Malamud2004c}` instead of `\cite[p. 694]{Malamud2004c}`, works for me

Perhaps, this is related to `apacite`.